# Can you calculate the size of a RandomForest before you run it?

Tags: r, random-forest

When running RandomForest, is there a way to use the number of rows and columns from the input data, plus the options of the forest (trees and trys) to calculate the size of the forest (in bytes) before it's run?

The specific issue I'm having is when running my final RandomForest (as opposed to exploratory), I want as robust a model as possible. I want to run right up to my memory limit without hitting it. Right now, I'm just doing trial and error, but I'm looking for a more precise way.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to run right up to my memory limit without hitting it.

Why do you want to do that?  Instead of pushing your resources to the limit, you should instead just use whatever resources are required to build a good random forest model.  In my experience, I have rarely ran into memory limit problems when running random forests.  This is because I train on a subset of the actual data set which is reasonably sized.

The `randomForest` function (from the `randomForest` package) has two parameters which influence how large the forest will become.  The first is `ntree`, which is the number of trees to be used when building the forest.  The fewer the trees, the smaller the size of the model.  Another parameter is `nodesize`, which controls how many observations will be placed into each leaf node of each tree.  The *smaller* the node size, the more splitting which has to be done in each tree, and the larger the forest model.

You should experiment with these parameters, and also train on a reasonably-sized training set.  The metric for a good model is not how close you come to maxing out your memory limit, but rather how robust a model you build.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your point. Still, the trial and error method isn't ideal for me. I am curious if there is a way I can estimate the size before it runs.